# Laravel 5.5 - "Call to a member function sync() on null" Error

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to save post images. There is no problem with saving images or moving images to the uploads directory. But in `sync` section, it gives me that error.

(I have three tables. posts, media and pivot table)

Here is sync codes;

```
$media = Media::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subSecond(10))->pluck('id');

$post->media()->sync($media, true);
```

Media Model;

```
public function posts(){

    $this->belongsToMany('App\Post','media_post','image_id','post_id');
}
```

and Post Model

```
public function media() {

    $this->belongsToMany('App\Media','media_post','post_id','image_id');
}
```

Any advice ?

Comment: Given that there isn't a lot of code. It's a bit difficult to diagnose. However, the error suggests that the result from media() is null. I'd start there. Maybe var_dump it.

Comment: I checked with dd method, its not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning from your relationship method. Thats why.

```
public function media()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(...);
}
```

That is what you are doing, it doesn't have a `return`.

```
$n = null;
$n->sync(); // Call to a member function sync() on null

function a() { }
a()->sync(); // Call to a member function sync() on null
```

This is PHP. You defined a method that doesn't return anything, you end up with a `null` if you call it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what I need to add question. Everything seems normal.

Comment: You are right, I should add more information but I didn't know what codes I need to attach the question.. (also now edited the question, and add post and media model)

Comment: you have your answer, this done, the questions is over .... there is no more discussion ... read my answer it explains why you are getting 'null'  :)

Comment: yes probably it is, because there is no error with other part

Comment: it is not 'probably it', it is it

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "You defined a method to return nothing," ? Posts or media methods are a releationships. And now I am sync them with sync() method. $media variable could be null, but it is not. what is the "null" one in here ?

Comment: they are not 'relationship' methods, you would like them to be but they are not, because they DO NOT return a Relation object. There is NO `return` in your methods. They `return` nothing.

Comment: You need to say this at first, hours and hours I tried figure out where is the mistake :/ But thanks, finally works

Comment: the first comment on your question suggests that media() is returning null, you then say it is not ... people can't help you when you are not telling the truth

Comment: I tought you mean $media variable in there